# Timed out retrying after 4000ms: The command was expected to run against origin https://google.com but the application is at origin https://google.com

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test my website from cypress.io, but i am constantly getting above error.
I am facing issue will Signing in with google. I am using the cy.origin() method.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Basic tests', () => {

it.only('Login should happen', ()=>{
// cy.viewport(1280, 720)
cy.visit('https://internetcomputerservices.com')

cy.contains('Dashboard').click()
cy.contains('Sign in with Google').click()


cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', ()=>{
   cy.get('[aria-label="Email or phone"]').click().type('haswrfbi20@gmail.com')
});

})
```

})
[image: This is the image of the page after clicking "Sign in with Google"]

[image: Image of error]

Please help me

Comment: Is there a way for us to reproduce this?

Comment: `/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Basic tests', () => {
    it.only('Login should happen', ()=>{
    // cy.viewport(1280, 720)
    cy.visit('https://internetcomputerservices.com')
    cy.contains('Dashboard').click()
    cy.contains('Sign in with Google').click()
    cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', ()=>{
       cy.get('[aria-label="Email or phone"]').click().type('haswrfbi20@gmail.com')
    });
    })
})`

this is the code, i am testing site called, internetcomputerservice.com
Please help!

Comment: internetcomputerservices.com, i forgot the "s" after "service"

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't able to find the solution for testing google login, i have connected with team and they will most likely resolve this issue in cypress 10.10.0.

For meanwhile, you can use `token` to directly login, by-pass the google-login and test the website.
you can find the token by going to `developer tools` and there you will find `Application`, click on it, there you will find the token, copy it and paste it in below code.

Make sure to install the package before hand:

```
npm i cypress-localstorage-commands
```

Code:

```
describe("Basic tests", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit("---your-website-url---", {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        win.localStorage.setItem(
          "token",
          "---token-here---"
        );
      },
    });
  });
  it.only("should be able to run test 1", async () => {
    // write your first test here ----
  });
});
```

Comment: did you resolve this properly later on?

Comment: @trainoasis, oh yeah, i did!